# react native pager view : Seeing a blank screen when I use setPageWithoutAnimation to last page

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-pager-view

I am using version 5.1.11 on iOS. I am trying to jump to the last page using ref.current.setPageWithoutAnimation(lastPageIndex)

However, I see a blank screen and if I move my finger a little bit (left-right) on the screen it then shows me the UI. The UI is right there but it's out of focus.

This happens sometimes and sometimes it works correctly.

Can anyone guide me if I am missing something here?

Thank you.